# How can I access every 5th Div, from a container so i can then use jQuery's add Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

Hey Everyone, 
Here's what i'm trying to do..

i have div that will contain numerous other div (products in a shopping cart), say
up 50.

of these contained divs, i need to access every 5th div begging with 1, so it'd be div # 1, 6, 11, 16, 21 etc. and then use jQuery to Add Class to these divs.

can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

it would be hugely appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think it will be useful:http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 3):

`$('div:nth-child(5n+1)).addClass('my-class');`